# rails on ruby do loop not in the correct order, lines not in td appear at the top

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, loops, html-table

I've searched for this problem and haven't been able to find an answer so figured I would ask.

I have an ActiveRecord object being looped over with a .each do to generate a table with a row for each record.  Now I am trying to place a div at the bottom of the loop so that more rows can be added under each record using javascript.  The problem is that unless the div is inside a  tag (while it needs to be only inside a ), they all end up above the rest of the output of the loop like so:

```
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
```

Then there is an empty  at the bottom where the div was supposed to go, but it's empty

it should be

```
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<div>
</div>
</tr>
```

This is my view, the div i'm referring to is near the bottom.

Thank you for any help.

```
            <div class="collapse" id=<%="searchExpand#{@count}"%> >
                <div class="card card-body">
                    Loading
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', "/collator/#{@file_name}" %>
<h1>In show, <%= @search_id %> status code <%= @status_code %> </h1>
<h4> <%= @used_keywords.any? ? "Searched previously: #{@used_keywords}" : " These words have been searched for #{@used_keywords}" %> </h4>
    <%= @keywords %>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Keyword</th>
        <!--    <th scope="col">Title</th> -->
            <th scope="col">Shipper</th>
            <th scope="col">Cosignee</th>
            <th scope="col">Origin</th>
            <th scope="col">Destination</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Expand</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%@count = 1; previous_keyword = "" %>
        <% @shipment_records.each do |shipment| %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><a href=<%= "xxx/{shipment.url}" %> target ="_blank"><%="#{@count}" %> </a> </th>

                <td><%= shipment.shipper %></td>
                <td><a href=<%="https://www.google.com/search?q=#{CGI.escape(shipment.consignee)}"%> target="_blank"><%= shipment.consignee %></a></td>
                <td><%= shipment.origin %></td>
                <td><%= shipment.destination %></td>
                <td><%= shipment.date %></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="searchExpand(<%="'searchExpand#{@count}','#{shipment.consignee}'"%>);"data-toggle="collapse" data-target=<%="#searchExpand#{@count}"%> aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="searchExpand" >Deep Search</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <div class="collapse" id=<%="searchExpand#{@count}"%> >
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        Loading
                    </div>
                </div>
                </tr>
            <% @count +=1 %>

        <% end %>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have a `div` as an immediate child of a `tr` element. Generally, only `td` or `th` elements can be immediate children of a `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

The [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) for a `<tr>` is:

> Zero or more `<td>` and/or `<th>` elements; script-supporting elements (`<script>` and `<template>`) are also allowed

so a structure like:

```
<tr>
  <div>...</div>
</tr>
```

is not valid HTML and the browser will rewrite it to be valid, that's why things are moving around on you.

The solution is to use valid HTML, something more like:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="7">
    <div class="collapse" id=<%="searchExpand#{@count}"%> >
      <div class="card card-body">
        Loading
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and then adjust your JavaScript to properly deal with the new `<td>`.